# Which RPM package should I use to run Memgraph on RedHat 8?

Tags: memgraphdb

I see that there are multiple RPM packages (Centos 7, Centos 9, Fedora 36) of Memgraph. I have RedHat 8. I've tried to use Centos 9 RPM package.

Memgraph is installed, but when I am trying to start the memgraph service by running: `sudo systemctl start memgraph` nothing happens.

I also tried to run `sudo journalctl --unit memgraph` and I got:

```
Jan 28 13:03:53 host_name systemd[1]: Started Memgraph: High performance, in-memory, transactional graph database.
Jan 28 13:03:53 host_name systemd[1]: memgraph.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Jan 28 13:03:12 host_name systemd[1]: memgraph.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Can Memgraph be started on RedHat 8?